# Change which player the Xbox controller represents?

Tags: c++, directx, xbox360, xinput

Does anyone know if there is a way to change which portion of the ring is lit on the Xbox controller? For instance, I want the first controller to be plugged in to represent player 2 (if player 1 opts to use keyboard/mouse input)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use XInputRemap to remap the connected controllers to the users associated with those controllers. This is part of the XInput API. So if you have 2 players and want to swap their controller:

```
DWORD remap[XUSER_MAX_COUNT];
remap[0] = 1;
remap[1] = 0;
DWORD dwResult = XInputRemap(remap);
```

The SDK includes a sample the demonstrates this function.

Comment: Where did you find this function? I can't find any references to it in any documentation online, nor can I find it in xinput.h.